# iOS starts looking for image~ipad.png after some time instead of image.png

Tags: ios, image, ipad, xib

I have a pretty strange problem: after some time the images used in my UIs stops displaying on my iPad(not all, just the 80%).

I've checked it with instruments there is no memory leak and the app's total allocations is 5MB so memory should not be an issue.

I'm using xibs named like SomeViewController~ipad.

When I checked I/O Activity with instruments I noticed that after some time the app stops looking for background.png but looks for background~ipad.png and gives back "No such file or directory" error.

Is there something I can do to prevent this?

Comment: Is this happening for only certain images or randomly for all of them?

Comment: It could be that you've found a bug. I'd make a ~ipad.png copy of all images that are used with ~ipad.xib. If this will solve the problem you should file a bug and workaround. One more thing: is this an universal app or iPad app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've found out that it was some kind of bug in a iOS 5.0.x version. After upgrading to 5.1.1 the bug disappeared.